# Modify multiple variable names

Tags: r, dplyr, rename

I have a number of variables in a data.frame in R, called `Offshore, EA19, NON_EA19` and many more. What's the easiest way to put a "P_" in front of every variable's name, so that they're called `P_Offshore, P_EA19, P_NON_EA19`?

Preferably in dplyr.

Comment: If you want to rename all the variables, you can use `mtcars %>% setNames(paste0("P_", names(.)))` if you like pipes

Comment: An alternative: `names(mydf) <- sub("^", "P_", x = names(mydf))`

Comment: Or just `names(df) <- paste0("P_", names(df))`

Comment: @docendo discimus, since there is only one single variable for which I do not want to change the name, this is a well enough approximation.